# API Ignored, Home View Called

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Was coaching a colleague on Web API. Just trying to run the default Web API template out of the Visual Studio box, as it were...not even doing anything fancy. A default (Get) call to my API (api/{controller}/{id}) keeps returning the MVC home view instead of the contents of the Get method in my API controller.

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
...

namespace WebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked far and wide across the 'Net but can't find anything address my specific problem.

I expected the default value1, value2, etc. Instead, the MVC home view keeps returning instead.

Comment: The project is most likely a mixed mvc and Web api project. Calling default root with / will go to home page of mvc not Web api

Comment: URL I'm calling is http://localhost:XXXX/api/values

Calling value, singular, results in an error.

Comment: So far everything looks in order

Comment: Just cleaning up some of the comments that are no longer needed. I'm still looking into this.

Comment: I know, right? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Create a another new project from scratch and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Nkosi - the only reason I hesitate to do that is I'd like to know what the error is, for future reference. Yes, I'm just that stubborn. :-)

Comment: I totally understand. But first lets see if you can move past the error and then come back to see what may have been the cause. If the new project works then we have a control to compare against. If it does not work then we have confirmation that it is reproducible.

Comment: Created another project and it works. Am comparing files now to see why the first one broke.

Comment: Glad to see progress was made. Happy Coding.